# python subprocess - cat command without argument shutdown the program

Tags: python, subprocess

I know when running `cat` without a file stuck in standard input.

I tried the following:
But it didn't work.

```
 try: 
   cmdinput = input("->")
   cmd = subprocess.getoutput(f'{cmdinput}', errors='ignore')
   print(cmd)  
 except subprocess.SubprocessError:   
   print("please use cat with a file")
```

I dont want to do this:

```
cmdinput = input("->")
if cmdinput == "cat":
  print("please use cat with a file")
else:
  cmd = subprocess.getoutput(f'{cmdinput}', errors='ignore')
  print(cmd)
```

Which exception should i use?

Comment: `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` and it'll just exit immediately when no file is given. There's no reason for any exception at all.

Comment: i dont want the program to exit because i have it in a while loop

Comment: I'm not saying your Python script will exit, I'm saying `cat` will exit instead of hanging when not passed any filenames if you attach its stdin to `/dev/null`, so you don't have the problem in the first place and don't need to do any special-case handling for it.

Comment: `cat` isn't the only program that tries to read from the terminal. Most programs that expect filename arguments will default to standard input if you don't give them any arguments.

Comment: Also, many programs treat the filename `-` as a synonym for standard input, e.g. `cat -` will also hang.

Comment: getoutput doesnt have stdin argument

Comment: That may be so, but there's no good reason to use `getoutput`. Just use `subprocess.run()` or `subprocess.Popen` and you get the full set of capabilities, so you can control stdin _and_ collect stdout.